# How/where to clone current 18.04 kernel (5.0.0-37-generic), specifically using Git

Tags: 18.04, kernel, git, clone

I am looking to download/clone the source of kernel 5.0.0-37. I am looking to do this exclusively via Git. I know there are other ways to download the source, but I am looking for info on the Git repo that contains the 5.0.0-37 kernel. If anyone knows what it is, can you please share it?

Answer (score 3):

All kernel sources for Ubuntu 18.04 `bionic` can be found at https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git

The `master` branch contains the initial `4.15` kernel.

The `hwe` branch has the latest [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) kernel. It is `5.0` at the moment.

The `hwe-edge` has the next HWE `5.3` kernel.

There are some other branches that can also be checked out if needed.

You can get the latest HWE kernel by running:

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git
cd ubuntu-bionic
git checkout hwe
```

That will get the current [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) bionic that is the `5.0.0-37` kernel now.

Comment: This is exactly the info I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: My only remaining question is, how did you know to checkout with 'hwe' for 5.0.0.-37?  Where exactly did you find that info?

Comment: I added this to the answer.