# Fake CSR 4.0 Bluetooth Dongle with error Set Event Filter(Invalid HCI Command Parameters) after kernel patch

Tags: drivers, usb, 20.04, kernel, bluetooth

I've got a fake dongle BT 4.0 from china and try the procedure from this thread:  [Bluetooth dongle problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205962/bluetooth-dongle-problem)

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Device: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
    bcdDevice: 88.91
    Kernel: 5.10.3-051003-generic

usb-devices | awk '/0a12/' RS=
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0a12 ProdID=0001 Rev=88.91
S:  Product=BT DONGLE10
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
```

But even after patch, I'm getting the error below via hcidump:

```
HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    Set Event Filter (0x03|0x0005) ncmd 1
    status 0x12
    Error: Invalid HCI Command Parameters
```

Check it: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60824#c155

"Same device and same issue on Pi Zero. "Changing the `#define lmp_bredr_capable(dev)` in `hci_core.h` to return false did the trick."

I don't know how to do that #define lmp_bredr_capable(dev). Could someone help?

I'm fully available to test it.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Anyway you need to build a kernel from source to use that fix.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04. I was running a script from here: https://gist.github.com/nevack/6b36b82d715dc025163d9e9124840a07

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by comment the lines 296 and 297 of **hci_core.c**(plus patches).

```
static void bredr_setup(struct hci_request *req)
{
    __le16 param;
    __u8 flt_type;

    /* Read Buffer Size (ACL mtu, max pkt, etc.) */
    hci_req_add(req, HCI_OP_READ_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, NULL);

    /* Read Class of Device */
    hci_req_add(req, HCI_OP_READ_CLASS_OF_DEV, 0, NULL);

    /* Read Local Name */
    hci_req_add(req, HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_NAME, 0, NULL);

    /* Read Voice Setting */
    hci_req_add(req, HCI_OP_READ_VOICE_SETTING, 0, NULL);

    /* Read Number of Supported IAC */
    hci_req_add(req, HCI_OP_READ_NUM_SUPPORTED_IAC, 0, NULL);

    /* Read Current IAC LAP */
    hci_req_add(req, HCI_OP_READ_CURRENT_IAC_LAP, 0, NULL);

    /* Clear Event Filters */
    //flt_type = HCI_FLT_CLEAR_ALL;  HERE!!
    //hci_req_add(req, HCI_OP_SET_EVENT_FLT, 1, &flt_type);

    /* Connection accept timeout ~20 secs */
    param = cpu_to_le16(0x7d00);
    hci_req_add(req, HCI_OP_WRITE_CA_TIMEOUT, 2, &param);
```

Maybe the "#define lmp_bredr_capable(dev) 0" also work. But im not sure. I still run the bredr_setup() but bypass the clear event filter step...

**obs: Its working flawless for 2 days. Only problem, i cant turn it into a HSP\HSP profile but i think its another story(even after the ofono gambiarra). Bluetooth in linux is a pain in a$..**

Answer (score 0):

I have found that just upgrading to Kernel 5.13.4 fixes the Fake Bluetooth CSR 0100 issue.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
```

Then check updates and install the tool via commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

Search in Linux Programs Kernel Mainline updater and run the upgrade, reboot, Fake CSR Bluetooth working.